Не работает передача сообщения
У меня уже написан ТГ бот и ранее он был оформлен в 1 файле. Решил его оптимизировать, раскидав функционал по разным файлам. В итоге у меня есть пункт "рассчитать стоимость заказа", где, при нажатии, пользователь должен ввести сумму товара в вызываемой функции calculator из файла Calculator_priceи бот должен передать информацию в следующую функцию путем передачи сообщения
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, calculation_summ)
Только существует проблема, при которой он просто читает сообщение и не выдает ничего в ответ, просто молчит...
Передача изначальной информации идет путем
if (message.text == "Калькулятор стоимости"):
    Calculator_price.calculator(message)

Внутри другого файла осуществляется работа:
def calculator(message):
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите стоимость товара в юанях: ")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, calculation_summ)

def calculation_summ(message):
    if (message.text.isdigit()):
        summ = message.text
        summ = int(summ)
        liberty_percent = summ * (liberty / 100)
        price = (summ + liberty_percent) * yan
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Итоговая примерная сумма: {round(price, 2)} + {500} рублей/кг за доставку")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели некорректрную цену или допустили ошибку при вводе! Повторите сначала!")
        calculator(message)


проверьте принтом calculation_summ есть ли какой-то отклик?

@oleksandrigo, здравствуйте, проверил... он просто молчит, не пишет ничего в консоль, просто "кушает" ответ

@oleksandrigo, я нашел ошибку: при передаче сообщения, когда пользователь (пока что только я) отправляет сообщение, в следующую функцию передается информация None, что означает, что ничего не передается... и я не знаю, как это пофиксить
